# How to connect ExoPlayer inside Service with ExoPlayerView inside activity?

Tags: android, pass-by-reference, exoplayer

I want to add "Fullscreen" button to the standard SimpleExoPlayer implementation from Google. I added the ImageButton and everything works well so far.

Then I decided that fullscreen will work in next way: after pressing on button, I open new activity with fullscreen SimpleExoPlayerView, pass there video uri and current position, initialize player and seek for given position. It works, but the player re-initialization takes 1-3 seconds depending on a device what don't want to have.

Now I would like to have an instance of player inside intent service and just reattach existing player to any view that wants to show it (preview or fullscreen view), like this:

```
mPlayerView.setPlayer(mPlayer);
```

The problem is that service will have the player and activity will have the view. No one of them will have both to be able to attach player to view. As a workaround, I think about making that the service class may have a static link to the player, so activity will be able to get it via static reference. But this seems like some code smell and I don't know if there won't be problems with communications between threads.

So, how can I pass the player from Service (that is not Serializable or Parcelable) to Activity or how can I pass a player view to the Service?

Comment: try to bind service to get player instance. https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html

Answer (score -2, accepted):

exoPlayer handle fullscreen good enough - try to change your layout params of playerView to match the screen on rotation or pressing button.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    int width;
    int height;

    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    int uiOptions;

    if(newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        Resources r = getResources();
        float px = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 300, r.getDisplayMetrics());
        width = CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        height = (int)px;
        uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE;
    } else {
        uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;
    }

    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
    final CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams lp = new CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams(width, height);
    mAppBar.setLayoutParams(lp);
}
```

Also don't forget to add this to your activity manifest to prevent activity reload:

```
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|screenLayout|smallestScreenSize|uiMode"
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The question was "how can I pass the player from Service to Activity or how can I pass a player view to the Service?".

Answer (score 0):

I have faced a similar issue with Video Playback using MediaPlayer. I have bound to MediaBrowserService using IBinder and then fetched the MediaPlayer instance. In your service provide a method that returns a reference to MediaPlayer. Something like this:

```
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals("YOUR_INTENT")) {
        return new LocalBinder();
    }
    return super.onBind(intent);
}

public class LocalBinder extends Binder{
    public AudioService getService(){
        return AudioService.this;
    }
}

public MediaPlayer getMediaPlayer() {
    return mediaPlayer;
}
```

In your Activity/Fragment then bind to MediaBrowserService using IBinder. In my implementation, I have used MediaPlayer, but I think in similar ways it can be used for Exoplayer.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
private SurfaceView surfaceView;
private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
private boolean isServiceBounded;
private boolean isSurfaceReady;

private ServiceConnection serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        isServiceBounded = true;
        mediaPlayer = ((AudioService)service).getMediaPlayer();
        if (isSurfaceReady) {
            mediaPlayer.setDisplay(surfaceHolder);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        isServiceBounded = false;
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    surfaceView = findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
    surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
    surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
    bindService(new Intent("YOUR_INTENT"), serviceConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    surfaceHolder = holder;
    isSurfaceReady = true;
    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
        mediaPlayer.setDisplay(holder);
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    isSurfaceReady = false;
    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
        mediaPlayer.setDisplay(null);
    }
    surfaceHolder = null;
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    unbindService(serviceConnection);
}
```

}